# SEGW error Object components locked in different requests after releasing service class before extending entity

Tags: abap, sap-gateway

I am facing an annoying problem. During my development work I modified some methods of the `*DPC_EXT` classes of a Gateway service in `SE24`. After releasing the task containing these changes I realized one of this service's entities needed some extra properties added in `SEGW`. I added them and saved them in a new task within the same transport request as the original. But when generating the runtime artifacts I always receive the following error:

> Object components locked in different requests

I have tried un-releasing the released task using program `RDDIT076` but this is no longer possible. `RDDIT076` can't change task statuses anymore due to security concerns.

Is there some benign trick to resolve this issue? Or should the transport request just be imported by our SAP BASIS team and should we start with a clean slate?

Thank you in advance,
Joshua

Comment: did you release the task or not? did you release the TR? which exact object did you place into second task? DPC class method?

Comment: Different task in same request should be no error whatsoever. Are you sure there are no artifacts distributed in different requests?

Comment: A member of our BASIS team moved some methods to a different transport request which resolved the issue in the end.